# Grabbing specific sections of text from a string with awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm looking to obtain two fields from a string. Here's the example:

```
$_LANG['field1'] = "field two";
```

I want to be able to return: field1 fieldtwo

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "[\"']" '{ print $2, $4 }' file
```

Results:

```
field1 field two
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I just get a 2ndry prompt with your awk-statement.

Comment: @tink: Please see the update. HTH.

Comment: @steve. it again tooke me sometime to figure out what u did :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*'\''\(.*\)'\''.*"\(.*\)".*/\1 \2/'
```

escaping ' in shell <3

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ey:\"\':\\n\\n: -e'/[^\n]*\n/s:::;/\n[^\n]*\n/s:: :;/\n.*$/sxxx' FILE
```

Other possibility:

```
sed -ey:\"\':\\n\\n: -e'/[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\)\n[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*/ sxx\1 \2x'
```

Other variant:

```
cat FILE | tr [\'\"] \\n\\n | sed '3h;6H;${x;s:\n: :p};d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r "s/.*'(.*?)'.*\"(.*?)\".*/\1 \2/" file
```

Results:

```
field1 field two
```